# Lightroom upload to Flickr: Replace Re-Published photos

Tags: lightroom, flickr, publishing

I connected my Flickr account to Lightroom in order to upload photos. After uploading an album, I edited a couple of the pictures in this album. Now, they appear under "Modified Photos To Republish" in the Flickr section of Lightroom. When I click the publish button to re-publish these photos, they get added a second time to the Flickr album.

Is is possible to tell either Lightroom or Flickr to replace these photos instead of adding them a second time?

All I want is to exchange all photos in Flickr that have been edited in Lightroom with the edited versions. Currently the only way I figured out to achieve this is deleting the album on Flickr and re-uploading it via Lightroom.

I'm using Lightroom 5.5 on mac OS X

**Edit:**
I have been able to solve the problem by updating Lightroom to version 5.6. Now, Lightroom asks if there are photos that are already on the server and offers replacing them

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/lightroom_5_3_republish_with_flickr_issue) but that also depends on what version of Lightroom you are using.

Comment: @mivilar I added some info about my Lightroom version

Comment: You can certainly replace it from Flickr, but that means doing it one file at a time from the site.  No involvement from Lightroom at all in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a daily user of user in Flickr using my Lightroom 5.5 to upload to photostream in Flickr.

When you are in Library mode with the grid view of your photostream it shows you any files you have modified that were previously published in your Flickr photostream.

If you click the publish button lightroom asks you if you would like to replace the existing file with the modified file. It also gives you the option to skip or cancel.

I do not believe it will delete all your views, comments or favorites but let me try while I am writing this.

Nope, it just updates existing photo with new data, its location and comments stay in place in Flickr.

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you have a Pro-Account or a Free account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you, but am wondering if you're sure you want to replace them? The downside of replacing them is that you'll lose all the views, comments, likes etc. that the photos have had in Flickr since you first published them - so it seems to me it's like starting anew, even if you would be replacing them rather than re-publishing them.

Comment: The photos I'm talking about are private, so I don't care about views or comments.

Comment: Not sure about the views, but it keeps the comments and all other settings (sets, groups...).